# Security implications of fetching unknown url from server

Tags: node.js, security

I have an application where users can give an API URL and then that URL is hit on a schedule (example: fetch data from SpaceX API every 25 minutes).

If the server is a node.js app, are there any security implications I need to worry about? By fetching data from an unknown URL (using `node-fetch`), what could go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your app is exposed to [SSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Server_Side_Request_Forgery),

> In a Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF) attack, the attacker can abuse functionality on the server to read or update internal resources. The attacker can supply or modify a URL which the code running on the server will read or submit data to, and by carefully selecting the URLs, the attacker may be able to read server configuration such as AWS metadata, connect to internal services like http enabled databases or perform post requests towards internal services which are not intended to be exposed.

For example, if your app is hosted on AWS EC2, your attacker can provide a url (http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/role-name) to local AWS meta-data services, which may expose AWS **token** to the attacker.
This attack assumes that the result of the request is returned to the attacker.

[Mitigation of SSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Server_Side_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) attacks

Comment: Is this problem mitigated by using a proxy / VPN service? Or are there better ways to mitigate this?

Comment: Proxy / VPNs are not relevant, it is not a matter of interception but a matter of making your serve make a request to internal infrastructure, which is not public.
In order to mitigate SSRF, read the article I've added